# JAXB Implementations

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have an xml with dynamic structure. For example:

```
<aggregator>
    <aggregationType>Voting</aggregationType>
    <decimalPrecision>4</decimalPrecision>
    <seed>2</seed>
    <HTepsilon>0.0050</HTepsilon>
    <WLWmaxIterations>100</WLWmaxIterations>
    <WLWepsilon>0.0050</WLWepsilon>
</aggregator>
```

In the above xml the `aggregator` tag can have a varying structure. It depends on aggregationType.

The tags `HTepsilon`, `WLWmaxIterations` and `WLWepsilon`, presence depends on the `aggregationType`.

As of now these tags need to be mentioned in the xml always, but I am looking forward to change this in such a way that they have an entry based on aggregationType tag.

In that case how should I be defining my Java class for this tag. As of now I am doing a comparison of aggregationType to all possible values and retrieve the corresponding tags values.

A small error in the code in one place can prove fatal in this design.

Comment: `aggregationType` controls what is written out to XML, what is read in, or both?

Comment: Sorry I did not see your comment. It was just un-marshaling that I was concerned about. Anyways I worked upon the design and solved it. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "The tags HTepsilon, WLWmaxIterations and WLWepsilon, presence depends on the aggregationType". Can you expand on "dependency" policy. I suggest you strat from defining the XSD, where you define your data model. JAXB can generate java classes for you from the XSD definition.

Comment: I meant those tags may or may not be present in the xml file based on aggregationType. e.g. when the aggregationType is voting actually all three of them won't be there(not just empty the tags will be removed from the file). instead when the value of aggregationType  is say WLW <WLWepsilon> tag will be mentioned.

Comment: @s2s, If they are just optional, then do not need to do anything. The object fields will be set to null. What (framework/technology/etc.) are you using for converting from xml to object.

Comment: Hey! I am using JAXB with no annotations. As of now I have implemented it the way you have suggested above, and this is just part a of the xml file I am using in my application and doing null check for the entire hierarchy is kind of error prone. Is this the only way to solve or are there more useful frameworks, using which I can avoid the null check? I understand my queries are too abstract but I am just trying to explore more XML frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

What about defining a base Aggregator type, and then define the necessary extensions. For example:

```
<xsd:complexType name="Aggregator" abstract="true">
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="aggregationType" type="xsd:string">
</xsd:element>      
<xsd:element name="decimalPrecision" type="xsd:int">
</xsd:element>      
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="HTepsilonAggregator">
<xsd:complexContent>
<xsd:extension base="Aggregator">
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="HTepsilon" type="xsd:double"></xsd:element>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:extension>
</xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply. I worked up on the design and changed the approach. Once again thanks to you and madhav for the suggestions.